# Campo input não fica alinhado com os outros

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Por algum motivo que ainda não descobri o campo "Estado Civil" não fica alinhado ao campo "Disponibilidade nos Sabados".

Não estou utilizando CSS nesse arquivo, pois é só um esboço da versão final.

```
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                            <div class="footer-header"> 
                                <h2 style="color:red;">Trabalhe Conosco</h2> 
                            </div>  
                        </div>              
                    </div><!--row-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

                             <form action="envio-curriculo.php" method="post" id="my_form">                       
                                <div><div /><input required="required" type="text" placeholder="Nome Completo" value="" name="nome" id="nome" class="form-control"></div></div><br>
                                <div class="col-md-6"><input required="required" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" value="" name="email" id="email" class="form-control"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-6"><input required="required" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone para contato" type="text" class="form-control"></div>
                                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="dataNascimento">Data de nascimento</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dataNascimento" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa">
  </div>
                                  <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="setor">Setor Desejado</label>
                                    <select id="setor" class="form-control" >

                                        <option value="Administrativo" style="background-color: black">Administrativo</option>
                                        <option value="Comercial" style="background-color: black">Comercial</option>
                                        <option value="Operacional / Técnico" style="background-color: black">Operacional / Técnico</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="Disponibilidade">Disponibilidade nos Sabádos</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="Disponibilidade">
                                  <option value="" style="display: none;"></option>
                                  <option value="Sim">Sim</option>
                                  <option value="nao">Não</option>
                                </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                  <label for="estadoCivil">Estado Civil</label>
                                  <select id="estadoCivil" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="solteiro">Solteiro(a)</option>
                                    <option value="casado">Casado(a)</option>
                                    <option value="divorciado">Divorciado(a)</option>
                                    <option value="viuvo">Viúvo(a)</option>
                                    <option value="unido">União Estável</option>
                                  </select>
                                </div>

                                <div><textarea id="message" class="form-control" rows="3" name="mensagem" placeholder="Informações Adicionais" style="resize: none;"></textarea></div><br>
                                <div align="center">
                                    <div>
                                        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 10px" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfOUwgUAAAAAEscevglagePmbzPKKRO6NfzUpUl"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <br>
                                 <div class="m-2">
                                        <label class="btn btn-default btn-file" >Anexar Currículo:
                                            <input required="required" type="file" name="curriculo" >
                                        </label>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div><input  class="contact_button button btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_curriculo" value="Enviar" /></div>

                                <div  id="server-results"><!-- For server results --></div>
                            </form> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cara para o grid do Bootstrap funcionar o pai de uma `col` tem que ser um `row`, e não simplesmente sair colocando `cols` e esperar que elas se alinhem. Recomendo fortemente que vc pare um pouco para dar uma olhada na documentação do Grid do Bootstrap, vai te ajudar muito. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Além disso tem várias `divs` desnecessárias no seu código e fechadas no lugar errado, vc tem que ter atenção a isso para não quebrar o layout.

Olha ai como ficou o código corrigido.

**OBS:** Exiba em página toda para ver eles lado a lado, pois como vc colocou `col-md-6` em telas pequenas eles ficam mesmo um acima do outro

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<style>

</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="footer-header">
                    <h2 style="color:red;">Trabalhe Conosco</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--row-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

                <form action="envio-curriculo.php" method="post" id="my_form">
                    <input required="required" type="text" placeholder="Nome Completo" value="" name="nome" id="nome" class="form-control">

                    <br>

                    <div class="row">
                      
                      <div class="col-md-6"><input required="required" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" value="" name="email" id="email" class="form-control"></div>
                      <div class="col-md-6"><input required="required" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone para contato" type="text" class="form-control"></div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="dataNascimento">Data de nascimento</label>
                          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dataNascimento" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                          <label for="setor">Setor Desejado</label>
                          <select id="setor" class="form-control">
  
                              <option value="Administrativo" style="background-color: black">Administrativo</option>
                              <option value="Comercial" style="background-color: black">Comercial</option>
                              <option value="Operacional / Técnico" style="background-color: black">Operacional / Técnico</option>
                          </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                          <label for="Disponibilidade">Disponibilidade nos Sabádos</label>
                          <select class="form-control" id="Disponibilidade">
                              <option value="" style="display: none;"></option>
                              <option value="Sim">Sim</option>
                              <option value="nao">Não</option>
                          </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                          <label for="estadoCivil">Estado Civil</label>
                          <select id="estadoCivil" class="form-control">
                              <option value="solteiro">Solteiro(a)</option>
                              <option value="casado">Casado(a)</option>
                              <option value="divorciado">Divorciado(a)</option>
                              <option value="viuvo">Viúvo(a)</option>
                              <option value="unido">União Estável</option>
                          </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div><textarea id="message" class="form-control" rows="3" name="mensagem" placeholder="Informações Adicionais" style="resize: none;"></textarea></div><br>
                    <div align="center">
                        <div>
                            <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 10px" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfOUwgUAAAAAEscevglagePmbzPKKRO6NfzUpUl"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <br>
                    <div class="m-2">
                        <label class="btn btn-default btn-file">Anexar Currículo:
                            <input required="required" type="file" name="curriculo">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div><input class="contact_button button btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_curriculo" value="Enviar" /></div>

                    <div id="server-results">
                        <!-- For server results -->
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Valeu pela dica mano, mas ainda sim o campo em especifico não fica alinhado aqui, não sei se é por motivos de navegador ou coisa do tipo

Comment: Cara se aqui funciona e ai não provavelmente é pq vc tem ai algum CSS extra que está atrapalhando ou pq vc não conferiu direito o código que coloquei ai acima, aqui ele está ficando assim http://prntscr.com/pmr8em mas logicamente por ser coluna 6 só até telas MD, em telas menos que isso fica só um input por linha mesmo.

Comment: o pioré que copiei o seu codigo e joguei lá

Comment: @SouzaElvis se aqui no site funciona, e aqui em casa funciona, ai tem que funcionar tb rss, além disso não consigo te ajudar mais, o que posso afirmar é que o código acima coloca os campos lado a lado, vc deve estar colocando algo a mais ou a menos no seu... sugiro copiar o código da resposta e testar de forma insolada em um arquivo novo só com o Bootstrap pra vc testar